# MySQL MATCH, AGAINST not works with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this simple code to make search results depending on relevance:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM `apps` WHERE MATCH(appName, appSeller) AGAINST("angry")');
$appCount = $stmt->rowCount();

echo $appCount;
```

And it's not showing any results!

Thanks in advance for your help,
Marcell

Comment: a) do you have a fulltext index on that table? b) did you check for query errors (you simply assume the query ran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   <?php
  // Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
   $hostdb = 'localhost';
   $namedb = 'tests';
   $userdb = 'username';
   $passdb = 'password';

 try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
 $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

 // Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `apps` WHERE MATCH(appName, appSeller) AGAINST("angry")";
 $stmt = $db->query($sql);

  // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($stmt not false)
 if($stmt !== false) {
  $cols = $stmt->columnCount();           // Number of returned columns

   echo 'Number of returned columns: '. $cols. '<br />';

 // Parse the result set
  foreach($stmt as $row) {
  echo $row['id']. ' - '. $row['name']. ' - '. $row['category']. ' - '. $row['link'].  '<br />';
 }
 }

 $db = null;        // Disconnect
 }
 print_r($sth->errorInfo());
 }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The real problem was the fulltext!

Answer (score 3):

Stackoverflow's usability is below zero.
Because there is no way to make a half-screen banner shown to everyone posting a question under PDO tag:

### Enable ERRMODE_EXCEPTION when connecting to PDO before asking a question.

Because it is pointless to ask without an error message, yet error message most likely will render a question unnecessary.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8';
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 'SELECT * FROM `apps` WHERE MATCH(appName, appSeller) AGAINST("angry")'
```

in phpmyadmin and see if it really returns anything.

Answer (score -1):

enclose your code in try and catch blocks, then you should get a clue to where your going wrong in your SQL syntax:

```
    try {

         // your code


    } catch ( PDOException £e ) {

         echo $e->getMessage();
         exit();

    }
```

Comment: exit, not die. its just stops executing the rest of the code. When an error occurs stop executing the rest of the code.